Non-hyphenated word for "equal-length" (not longer and not shorter)
Let's say we have two sequences A and B of differently coloured but equally big marbles.

If A has fewer marbles than B, we say that A's length is smaller than B's, and we would say that A is shorter than B.
If A has more marbles than B, we say that A's length is larger than B's, and we would say that A is longer than B.
But what single-word, non-hyphenated adjective do we have for the length being equal, meaning A is as long as B?

I can only think of multi-word phrases like "equal-length" or "same-length" or "equally sized" or "equal-size" and so on. Equidistant comes to mind, but that means equally apart rather than equally long, and I don't think equilongial is a thing. In any case, it is not correct to just use "equal" or "equivalent", because as opposed to two straight lines of the same length, two sequences of marbles can have the same length and still be very unequal in their contents.
There is only one similar thread on the same topic, but it is not about comparatives (shorter vs. longer) but positives (short vs. long) with the in-between being "medium". That's evidently not what I want.

For future reference of the comments: the original post mentioned the example of using this (single) word in a software program with existing routines countShorterSequences and countLongerSequences. This was not the main point, because the program's documentation is just in English. I would like to avoid "equal-length" there, since it seems clunky relative to "shorter" and "longer". Compare "this returns a longer, sorted sequence" with "this returns an equal-length, sorted sequence". As with all SWRs, you can always replace the word by an entire phrase ("this returns a sorted sequence of the same length"), but I don't want that.

@downvoter: please specify what is wrong with this question so I can improve it.

Requesting names for software labels and bins and GUIs is specifically off topic here. Not the downvoter, btw.

I'm wondering why "countEqualSequences is not correct" just because it doesn't exclude similar meanings 100%. It serves your purposes in context as you'll use it. Also, countAsLongSequences.

@PhilSweet The question can be easily divorced from software. It has nothing to do with a graphical interface; it is purely for myself to make my programming as well-legible as possible.

countEquallySizedSequences

@YosefBaskin Because equal sequences are only a subset of equal-length sequences.

@jxh Those are two words, and adverbs are particularly not-done in backend software.

Not done? The compiler doesn't malign adverbs.

@YosefBaskin The compiler also doesn't malign snake_case in Java nor does the interpreter complain about camelCase in Python, yet they have style guides and entire user bases that do not appreciate violating these style guides.

Generally, software will prefer clarity for future readers over strict adherence to style guides if doing so will harm clarity. However, you could use countNeitherShorterNorLongerSequences.

@jxh That's 4 words, whilst this is still a single-word request ;-) Besides, I am not only asking the question for the purpose of using this word in identifiers, but also for when I'm writing documentation. I really don't like how clunky and verbose "equal-length sequences" or "equally sized sequences" read.

I am not posting answers :-) Anyway, your own post pondered "EqualLength" and rejected it because of clarity. I provided more clear multi-word alternatives, knowing they are not single-word answers. Again, clarity is more important for readers of software (and documentation).

I’m voting to close because questions constrained by the limitations of software programming are not on-topic here.

"can be easily divorced from software"—Sorry, not as I see it. The best word for this circumstance is simply equal. If I have two boards of equal length, I simply say that they're "equal." Every use of this word is reliant on context to answer "equal how?" The problem is, in variable-naming, we have no surrounding body of prose to provide that context. In ordinary language usage, adding extra clarifying words like "equal in length," or hyphenating "equal-length," would be fine; the limitations here are due to the medium. The short answer is, sorry, there's no corollary to "equidistant."

OED possibly lists other-than-triangle-related broadenings for 'isosceles' and 'equilateral' ... but doubtless best avoided.

@EdwinAshworth Yes, I also looked up "equilateral equidistant equi-" but did not find anything like "equilonginal" or the like. Unfortunately the question was not appreciated due to me giving too much context.

I think you can edit it. Just omit references to computing. Line- and object-length are fine, and sentence-length perhaps in terms of number of words (number of characters becomes rather esoteric, and someone will raise the objections that different characters, dashes etc have different lengths). Note that 'shorter' / 'longer' are usually found as 'shorter/longer than', with usual analogue 'as long as' or 'equal in length to'.

Yes, more words would be more clear. countSequencesShorterThan, countSequencesLongerThan, countSequencesAsLongAs

There is a single word to consider, but it would be very strange in context: isomorphic. This is a mathematical concept, and using it would mean to find sequences for which there is a bijective mapping to the input sequence. Since the sequences are finite, it would mean the sequences are of the same length. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity

I would like to avoid "equal-length" there, since it seems clunky relative to "shorter" and "longer" You think a single word meaning "of equal length" would be  less clunky? LOL

OED has the obsolete word evenlong (adj.) with the meaning "Equally long, of the same length."

I’m voting to close because questions constrained by the limitations of software programming are not on-topic here.

@Greybeard You are purposefully misrepresenting my edit, which explicitly mentions that what you just said is besides the point. Please do not do that.

The term equisized can be put to service here.

Of equal size.

Wikitionary
While not a major dictionary, the word does appear in several reference sources, and ngram show some usage starting early last century.

The N-gram comparison between evenlong and equisized and equisize is surprisingly fair too. Any idea if these can be ranked orthogonal to Google N-gram?

"Congruent" comes to mind.
MW

congruent. Adjective.
2: superposable so as to be coincident throughout
congruent triangles


Isometric -  "of, relating to, or characterized by equality of measure" (Merriam-Webster)
It is a bit more vague than requested, because strictly speaking, the "measure" doesn't have to be length but come on! What other measure would you care about in a series? Width? Depth? :)
